# Use ansible to create GitHub repository with README

Tags: ansible, github

We use Ansible to automatically setup Kubernetes clusters.
KPT https://kpt.dev/ is further used to deploy config files to pods in these clusters.

In this process we need to create new GitHub Repositories with Ansible.
The problem is KPT doesn't work with en empty repo.

Is there a way to create a GitHub Repository with Ansible and include for example a README file? The file could be anything, doesn't matter for KPT.

I used the community.general.github_repo module to create a repository which worked great, but I don't seem to find a way to automatically include a README.md.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In GH API endpoint that is used in this module has the optional parameter `auto_init` - for the creation of empty `README` (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-an-organization-repository)

I see few options:

- create your own copy of this module - this easy change in the module
- change request in the module will be a good idea: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general

But probably the quickest way will be to use this module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html to call GH API